# PHP Retornar usuário do AD

Tags: php, ad

Possuo a query abaixo, que busca o nome completo do usuário cadastrado do AD:

```
<?php

//Conexao com AD
$ldapconfig['host']= '192.168.203.99'; //AD-001
$ldapconfig['port']= '389'; //Porta Padrão
$ldapconfig['dn'] = "";
$domain= 'peccin.local';
$username = 'diego.venuzka';
$password = 'xxxxxxx';

//Faz conexão com AD usando LDAP
$sn= ldap_connect($ldapconfig['host'], $ldapconfig['port']);
ldap_set_option($sn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($sn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

@$bind=ldap_bind($sn, $username .'@'.$domain, $password);


$filter = "(sAMAccountName=carlo*)";
$attributes = array('name');
$search = ldap_search($sn,'DC=peccin, DC=local', $filter, $attributes);

$data = ldap_get_entries($sn, $search);

foreach ($data AS $key => $value){

echo @$value["name"][0]."<br>";

}

?>
```

Nesse caso ele retorna o nome completo das pessoas que iniciam com **carlo**.

Existe alguma forma de conseguir pegar o campo **User Logon Name** abaixo? Tentei user, username, logonname, logon mas não consegui.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Diego, o que a var retorna se fizer `var_dump($value)`? Só pra constar, o `@` ali é desnecessário, creio eu.

Comment: O `sAMAccountName` seria o login? tenta `$attributes = array('name', 'sAMAccountName');`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, tens razão, o @ estava ali para ocultar o erro.

Comment: @rray isso ai, coloquei $attributes = array('sAMAccountName'); e retornou o usuario. Quiser postar como resposta.... obrigado!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `sAMAccountName` é o login, então para recuperar ele coloque esse campo na seleção dos atributos retornados.

```
$attributes = array('name', 'sAMAccountName');
```